# How to update the google geo location using the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I am very new to use geolocation, and my client provided a url and ask me to show all the loadtion which the url contains. the urls is:

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=119+5th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY+10003,+USA&hl=en&ll=40.713956,-73.828125&spn=146.915575,14.414062&sll=50.064192,-21.445312&sspn=141.347566,14.414063&oq=119+Fifth+Avenue+New+York+NY+10003+USA+&hnear=119+5th+Ave,+New+York,+10003,+United+States&t=m&z=2
```

And i got a sample work in web, and implemented, that's work fine. now i need to update my downloaded function to work  for above url and need to show all the location what the url(above) contains, i don't know to update to the function

any one help me to show updating my function to show all the location what my above `http` contains?

my downloaded function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', 40.713956, -73.828125, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', 146.915575, 14.414062, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', 50.064192, -21.445312, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', 141.347566, 14.414063, 2]
];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance. if any one put in fiddle then that would be fine.